# Keynote converter to pdf

Tags: pdf, graphics, keynote, file-conversion

I'd like to hide some parts of the pictures, that I import to keynote presentation (I use version 6.2 (1861)). To do this I overlay white rectangles without shades on top of these parts of the images and use white color as a background color of the slide.

However, when I convert a slide with an overlaid rectangle (although the background is white and the rectangle is filled with white) I get an artifact: thin edge line of the rectangle in black on my pdf. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use Print->"PDF"->"Save as pdf" instead of "Export To" and it seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a simple app like [Paintbrush](http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net/).

Modify, crop or cut the image to your liking.

Save it with new name (to keep the original).

This way you wont have the problems of trying to hide it in Keynote.

Comment: Thank you Buscar, but I believe this can't be an accepted answer as keynote should be able to properly convert presentation to pdf.